# What does this VB6 variable declaration do?

Tags: vb6, declaration

I just found this in some old code, and I'm not sure what it means.

```
Dim sTemp As String * 1
```

What is the * 1 at the end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that the variable is a string of exactly one character in length.

Essentially, a fixed-length string.

Comment: No. It can help with some COM API's though.

Comment: "Essentially, a fixed-length string."  - In this case, also essentially a character ;)

Comment: "Are there performance benefits to doing that?" Indeed there are because a fixed length string is a value type (a regular String is a reference type). There are drawbacks though due to lack of support in the VB model e.g. can't be used for subproc paramters or function return values.

Answer (score 4):

It's a fixed length string of one character. This was handy cause you could define a structure of fixed strings and read a file right into the structure.

Answer (score 3):

It creates a fixed-length string. In that example, the variable will only ever contain one character.